# Apache config error Require all

Tags: apache, configuration, config

After upgrading from apache 2.2 to 2.4 I have a strange apache config error. My vhost config file contains the following directory directive:

```
<Directory "C:/data/projectx/src/htdocs">  
            Options None 
            AllowOverride None
            #Order allow,deny   # old config style
            #Allow from all     # old config style
            Require all granted # new config style (replaces both rules above)
</Directory>
```

Which is conform with the new directive syntax. However, when I start apache I get this message, indicating some error on the `Require all` directive:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 22 of C:/data/projectx/src/admin/local.conf:
Argument for 'Require all' must be 'granted' or 'denied'
```

Obviously the error is somewhat misleading, as everything is correct. What is wrong with this directive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution: remove the comment after the `Require all` directive:

```
<Directory "C:/data/projectx/src/htdocs">  
            Options None 
            AllowOverride None
            #Order allow,deny   # old config style
            #Allow from all     # old config style
            # -->> moved comment into own line: new config style ...
            Require all granted 
</Directory>
```

Comment: I wonder who got the idea that the comments on the Require line should NOT be treated as comments, whereas comments on the same line as any other directive should be treated as comments ...

Comment: yeah, seems cookie. this solution worked for me. thanks stot!

Comment: cause I wonder how to make the CORS via server-side.